# SQL UNION Statement below eachother

Tags: mysql, sql

recently i´ve been experimenting around with the UNION function in sql statements, but i´ve come to a point where i cant get things how i want em.

so i´m trying to connect two querys together, one which gives me this output

```
ID |  DATE               | X
29 | 2016-07-31 20:00:00 | 0
27 | 2016-07-31 23:00:00 | 0
26 | 2016-07-31 23:22:00 | 0
```

Using this query :

```
SELECT * FROM table_entries WHERE closed='0' ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

And another one giving me this output

```
ID |  DATE               | X
28 | 2016-07-31 15:00:00 | 1
25 | 2016-07-31 01:00:00 | 1
24 | 2016-07-31 00:19:00 | 1
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_entries WHERE closed='1' ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

So i´ve tried combining them using UNION this way :

```
(SELECT * FROM table_entries WHERE closed='0' ORDER BY start_date ASC) UNION (SELECT * FROM table_entries WHERE closed='1' ORDER BY start_date DESC)
```

but instead of the expected statement of

```
ID |  DATE               | X
29 | 2016-07-31 20:00:00 | 0
27 | 2016-07-31 23:00:00 | 0
26 | 2016-07-31 23:22:00 | 0 
28 | 2016-07-31 15:00:00 | 1
25 | 2016-07-31 01:00:00 | 1
24 | 2016-07-31 00:19:00 | 1
```

it gives me this return

```
ID |  DATE               | X
26 | 2016-07-31 23:22:00 | 0
27 | 2016-07-31 23:00:00 | 0
29 | 2016-07-31 20:00:00 | 0
24 | 2016-07-31 00:19:00 | 1
25 | 2016-07-31 01:00:00 | 1
28 | 2016-07-31 15:00:00 | 1
```

What should i change to accomplish what i wanted in the beginning, or to "bind" these statements together so they append below eachother.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `UNION` for this query at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_entries
WHERE closed IN ('0', '1')
ORDER BY closed,
         (CASE WHEN closed = '0' THEN start_date END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN closed = '1' THEN start_date END) DESC;
```

It is *very* important to understand that SQL result sets have no inherent ordering (except in a few exceptional cases), unless the query has an `ORDER BY` clause.  This is because SQL is based on the notion of *unordered* sets.

`UNION`, in particular, needs to remove duplicates, which is additional processing.  However, you should never assume the ordering of a query unless you have an `ORDER BY` for the outer-most `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, you can use `conditional ordering` with  `case` in the `order by`:

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE closed='0' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE closed='1'
ORDER BY closed, 
    CASE WHEN closed = 0 THEN start_date ELSE '9999-12-31' END,
    CASE WHEN closed = 1 THEN start_date ELSE '1000-01-01' END DESC
```

Comment: The OP said the expected result was all the X = 0s first and then all the X = 1s

Comment: @kbball -- yeah, I was editing as you commented.  This is a case of `conditional ordering`...

Answer (score 0):

The query you wrote specifies DESC at the end instead of ASC. It should be like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM matches WHERE closed='0' ORDER BY start_date ASC)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM matches WHERE closed='1' ORDER BY start_date ASC)
```